# format-number(45,'#.##') returns '45.0'

Tags: saxon

I'm getting an unexpected result with Saxon PE 11.4.  `format-number(45,'#.##')` returns '45.0' instead of '45'.  But `format-number(45,'0.##')` does return '45'.  What am I misunderstanding here?

Answer (score 0):

I think this works as specified, i.e. https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#analyzing-picture-string says:

> If (after making the above adjustments) the minimum-integer-part-size
> and the minimum-fractional-part-size are both zero, then the
> minimum-fractional-part-size is set to 1 (one).